# Outputting 'null' for Option[T] in play-json serialization when value is None

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using play-json's macros to define implicit `Writes` for serializing JSON. However, it seems like by default play-json omits fields for which `Option` fields are set to `None`. Is there a way to change the default so that it outputs `null` instead? I know this is possible if I define my own `Writes` definition, but I'm interested in doing it via macros to reduce boilerplate code.

**Example**

```
case class Person(name: String, address: Option[String])

implicit val personWrites = Json.writes[Person]    
Json.toJson(Person("John Smith", None))

// Outputs: {"name":"John Smith"}
// Instead want to output: {"name":"John Smith", "address": null}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a custom implicit *JsonConfiguration*, see [Customize the macro to output null](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#Customize-the-macro-to-output-null)

```scala
implicit val config = JsonConfiguration(optionHandlers = OptionHandlers.WritesNull)

implicit val personWrites = Json.writes[Person]    
Json.toJson(Person("John Smith", None))
```

Answer (score 18):

The `Json.writes` macro generates a [`writeNullable[T]`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala#L392) for optional fields. Like you know (or not), `writeNullable[T]` omits the field if the value is None, whereas `write[Option[T]]` generates a null field.

Defining a custom writer is the only option you have to get this behavior.

```
( 
  (__ \ 'name).write[String] and
  (__ \ 'address).write[Option[String]]
)(unlift(Person.unapply _))
```

Answer (score 6):

Not a real solution for you situation. But slightly better than having to manually write the writes

I created a helper class that can "ensure" fields.

```
implicit class WritesOps[A](val self: Writes[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def ensureField(fieldName: String, path: JsPath = __, value: JsValue = JsNull): Writes[A] = {
      val update = path.json.update(
        __.read[JsObject].map( o => if(o.keys.contains(fieldName)) o else o ++ Json.obj(fieldName -> value))
      )
      self.transform(js => js.validate(update) match {
        case JsSuccess(v,_) => v
        case err: JsError => throw new JsResultException(err.errors)
      })
    }

    def ensureFields(fieldNames: String*)(value: JsValue = JsNull, path: JsPath = __): Writes[A] =
      fieldNames.foldLeft(self)((w, fn) => w.ensureField(fn, path, value))

}
```

so that you can write

```
Json.writes[Person].ensureFields("address")()
```

Comment: more safe and concise version of the same thing :

    `implicit class WritesOps[A](val self: OWrites[A]) extends AnyVal {
    def ensureFields(fieldNames: String*)(value: JsValue = JsNull, path: JsPath = _): OWrites[A] ={
    def tf(o: JsObject): JsObject = o ++ JsObject(fieldNames.withFilter(v => !o.keys.contains(v)).map( -> value)(collection.breakOut)) self.transform(tf(_)) 
    }
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Similar answer to above, but another syntax for this:

```
implicit val personWrites = new Writes[Person] {
  override def writes(p: Person) = Json.obj(
    "name" -> p.name,
    "address" -> p.address,
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

```
implicit val personWrites = new Writes[Person] {
  override def writes(p: Person) = Json.obj(
    "name" -> p.name,
    "address" -> noneToString(p.address),
  )
}

def optToString[T](opt: Option[T]) = 
   if (opt.isDefined) opt.get.toString else "null"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define something like this :

```
  implicit class JsPathExtended(path: JsPath) {
    def writeJsonOption[T](implicit w: Writes[T]): OWrites[Option[T]] = OWrites[Option[T]] { option =>
      option.map(value =>
        JsPath.createObj(path -> w.writes(value))
      ).getOrElse(JsPath.createObj(path -> JsNull))
    }
  }
```

And if you are using play framework :

```
  implicit val totoWrites: Writes[Toto] = (
      (JsPath \ "titre").write[String] and
        (JsPath \ "option").writeJsonOption[String] and
        (JsPath \ "descriptionPoste").writeNullable[String]
      ) (unlift(Toto.unapply))

   implicit val totoReads: Reads[Toto] = (
      (JsPath \ "titre").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "option").readNullable[String] and
        (JsPath \ "descriptionPoste").readNullable[String]
      ) (Toto.apply _)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap your option and redefine serialization behavior:

```
case class MyOption[T](o: Option[T])
implicit def myOptWrites[T: Writes] = Writes[MyOption[T]](_.o.map(Json.toJson).getOrElse(JsNull))
```

**CAVEATS:**

1)this approach is good only for case classes used solely as a serialization protocol definition. If you are reusing some data model classes in controllers - define custom serializers for them not to pollute the model.

2)(related only to Option) if you use the same class for writes **and reads**. Play will require the wrapped fields to be present (possibly null) during deserialization.

P.S.: Failed to do the same with type tagging. Compiler error is like
`No instance of play.api.libs.json.Writes is available for tag.<refinement>` (given the required writes were explicitly defined).
Looks like Play's macro fault.